# Get the event invoking page

Tags: jquery

Is there any way in jQuery to get the name of the document/page which has invoked the event?

below is the on change event which is common two pages and the elements in both the documents/pages have the class as new_featured_image

```
$( document ).on( "change", ".new_featured_image", function() {
        // code to get the document/page name
 });
```

Comment: do you want the previous page (before redirect) or do you want the current page?

Comment: @Robert current page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use jQuery, you can just read

```
window.location.href
```

and it will give you the address of the page (should be enough to identify the page).

Anyway, it's not really a clean way to achieve your goal. It's preferrable to add a class to your "body" tag depending on the page ("pageOne" and "pageTwo") and then use this class either to identify the page, something like:

```
 $( document ).on( "change", ".new_featured_image", function() { 
      if(body.hasClass("pageOne")) {...}
      else {...}
  });
```

or to add two different listeners:

```
 $( document ).on( "change", "body.pageOne .new_featured_image", function() { // code to get the document/page name });
 $( document ).on( "change", "body.pageTwo .new_featured_image", function() { // code
```